# Match data in a table based on data from another table SSRS, use colors

Tags: sql, background-color, ssrs-2012

I have two tables with two different data sets, lets call it `A` and `B`.
`Table A` contains target values for certain products e.g.:

Product  Limits        BLK BW  MDS MDTN  CDS  ......
 Napkin  Upper_Reject                    50 
 Napkin  Upper_Warning  78  20.3 9  1387  857
 Napkin  Target         73  19.6 7  1190  720
 Napkin  Lower_Warning  68  18.9 4  993   583
 Napkin  Lower_Reject   18.6 3.5    680   430

Daily Test Data:

Product BLK  BW   MDS  MDTN   CDS .......... 
 Napkin  71
 Napkin  74  20.1  4.94 1257   704
 Napkin  74
 Napkin  74  19.92 5.28 1188   737

`Table B` contains regular tests values for product `XYZ`, when `test01` for product `XYZ` is less than equal to 25 it shows color of `upper_reject` (whatever that is).

In a nutshell, `Table A` is range table and `Table B` is data table which has colors based on the range limit its in. Can someone explain that how can I achieve this in `SQL SERVER DATA TOOLS 2010`? `SSRS`

Comment: Add a sample dataset of table B. what is the table you want to conditionally change the background color?

Comment: Product    Test01 Test02 ........
XYZ            24         14

this way Test01 is under 25 when compared to table A hence within range.

i will upload a snapshot in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing you have a color column in the target table, you can use [lookup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210531.aspx) function to get the color that corresponds to the `test` value range.

I've created two sample datasets one for Taget and other for Tests.

[image]

To set background color conditionally based on test value, I've used the Target table ranges. I used the below expression for the `background-color` property of the row.

```
=Switch(
Fields!test.Value>Lookup("Upper_warning",Fields!Limits.Value,Fields!Test.Value,"Target"),
  Lookup("Upper_rejected",Fields!Limits.Value,Fields!Color.Value,"Target"),
Fields!test.Value>Lookup("Target",Fields!Limits.Value,Fields!Test.Value,"Target"),
  Lookup("Upper_warning",Fields!Limits.Value,Fields!Color.Value,"Target"),
Fields!test.Value=Lookup("Target",Fields!Limits.Value,Fields!Test.Value,"Target"),
  Lookup("Target",Fields!Limits.Value,Fields!Color.Value,"Target"),
Fields!test.Value<Lookup("Lower_warning",Fields!Limits.Value,Fields!Test.Value,"Target"),
  Lookup("Upper_rejected",Fields!Limits.Value,Fields!Color.Value,"Target"),
true,Lookup("Upper_warning",Fields!Limits.Value,Fields!Color.Value,"Target")
)
```

For every row in the test table it will compare the test field value against the Target table range and the correct color will be returned.

You can use this approach to get the get the presentation your tablix requires. Let me know if this helps you.

Comment: Fields!test.value?? i mean which column are we targeting here

Comment: `Fields!Test.Value` is the test value in the second table (Test table), In the example you put it is `test01` in the table B.

Comment: last statement `,
true,Lookup("Upper_warning",Fields!Limits.Value,Fields!Color.Value,"Target")
)` specifies the cell color. what is this statement actually doing???

Comment: all of the above statements have to be `TRUE` in order to execute the last `Lookup` ??

Comment: It says something like: if any previous expression doesn't evaluate to true use this color (the color returned by lookup).

Comment: another question, sometimes in the target table, Upper_Reject for Test01, Test02 ....... dont have values in them. and when we lookup to compare `Fields!BLK.Value>Lookup("Upper_Reject",Fields!Limits.Value,Fields!BLK.Value,"Target"),` then `Fields!BLK.Value` is always going to be greater. how do we fix this?

Comment: My logic says if BLK value is greater than the upper_warning value it will use the color for upper_rejected. It is evaluated by the first expression. However you can change the expression to get a default value if the BLK value is not present.

Comment: Thank you @alejandro. I have found another way with which i got the desired results.
I used
`=IIF ( Fields!ABS_01.Value <= Lookup("Upper_Warning",Fields!Limits.Value,Fields!ABS_01.Value,"Target") AND Fields!ABS_01.Value >= Lookup("Lower_Warning",Fields!Limits.Value,Fields!ABS_01.Value,"Target"),"Green", 
 IIF( Fields!ABS_01.Value > Lookup("Upper_Warning",Fields!Limits.Value,Fields!ABS_01.Value,"Target") AND Fields!ABS_01.Value < Lookup("Lower_Warning",Fields!Limits.Value,Fields!ABS_01.Value,"Target"), "Yellow", "Red") 
 )`
Thanks for the guideline

Comment: Sure, you are welcome. I hope my answer have been useful.

Comment: i ran into another issue. now the table for the test result for which we applied the above logic is still not 100%.
the issue is that the whole column value color changes if one value color changes.

Comment: I don't get what your issue is. You should create a new question and be more specific, since the current question was solved possibly it wont have the required visibility.